# Is there a way to filter JSON array by date in Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

The data is being pulled to get oil prices from Alberta, Canada. I'm pulling data using URL fetch but I only need data after Jan 1, 2010. The data is pulling 0 rows now though so is there anyway to filter by date?

```
function fetchOilPrices() { 
  var sheetName = 'Oil Prices';
  
  // Check if the sheet with the name already exists  
  var existingSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  if (!existingSheet) { 
    
  // If it does not exist, create a new sheet tab with the specific name    
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName); } 
  else { 
  
  // If it exists, assign it to newSheet    
  newSheet = existingSheet; } 
    
  var url = "https://api.economicdata.alberta.ca/api/data?code=0d593867-2089-4514-8901-9e2d7f666e0c"; 
  var options = {
      "method": "get",
  }; 

//Here's where I'm trying to filter the date      
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
  const dt = new Date(2010,0,1).valueOf();
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).filter(r => new Date(r[0]).valueOf() > dt)
    
  // Assuming the data is in an array  
  var observations = data; 
  var recentData = [["Date", "Type", "Value"]]; // Headers for the sheet 
    
  // Loop through observations and extract the necessary fields  
  observations.forEach(function(obs) { 
    recentData.push([obs.Date, obs['Type '], obs.Value]);
  }); 
 
  // Clear the sheet  
  newSheet.clearContents(); 
  Logger.log(sheetName + " cleared.") 
  
  // Write the data to the sheet  
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1, recentData.length, 3).setValues(recentData); 
  Logger.log("Written data for " + observations.length + " observations.");
}
```

I'm trying to add a date filter to the forEach loop but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  const dt = new Date(2010,0,1).valueOf();
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).filter(r => new Date(r[0]).valueOf() > dt)
```

This is your corrected code:

```
function fetchOilPrices() {
  var sheetName = 'Oil Prices';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sh) {
    var nsh = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  }
  else {
    nsh = sh;
  }
  var url = "https://api.economicdata.alberta.ca/api/data?code=0d593867-2089-4514-8901-9e2d7f666e0c";
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const dt = new Date(2010, 0, 1).valueOf();
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).filter(r => {
    let t = r["Date"].split("-")
    return new Date(t[0], Number(t[1]) - 1, 1).valueOf() > dt;
  })
  var observations = data;
  var recentData = [["Date", "Type", "Value"]]; // Headers for the sheet 
  observations.forEach(function (obs) {
    recentData.push([obs.Date, obs['Type '], obs.Value]);
  });
  nsh.clearContents();
  Logger.log(sheetName + " cleared.")
  nsh.getRange(1, 1, recentData.length, 3).setValues(recentData);
  Logger.log("Written data for " + observations.length + " observations.");
}
```